# How to configure collecd aggregate plugin to aggregate output from IPTable::Plugin?

Tags: iptables, collectd

I have enabled the [CollectD:IPTables plugin](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:IPTables) to track traffic to two different server groups:

```
LoadPlugin iptables

<Plugin iptables>
        Chain "filter" "TRACK_TRAFFIC_SERVER_A" "monitoring_traffic_server_a"
        Chain "filter" "TRACK_TRAFFIC_SERVER_B" "monitoring_traffic_server_b"
</Plugin>
```

Plugin returns tuples for each of the Chain with type *ipt_bytes* and *ipt_packets*.

Now I would like to have a metric that provide me sum of *ipt_bytes* and *ipt_packets* sent to SERVER_A and SERVER_B.

For that, I have enabled [CollectD:Aggregation plugin](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Aggregation) to provide this metric. This is the current configuration that **does not work**:

```
LoadPlugin aggregation

<Plugin "aggregation">
  <Aggregation>
    Plugin "iptables"
    Type "iptables"
    GroupBy "Host"
    GroupBy "TypeInstance"
    GroupBy "Type"
    CalculateNum false
    CalculateSum true
    CalculateAverage false
    CalculateMinimum false
    CalculateMaximum false
    CalculateStddev false
  </Aggregation>
</Plugin>
```

How to configure *aggregation plugin* to work with output of the Collectd::IPTables?

Comment: try removing: `GroupBy "Type"` and see. According to https://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/collectd.conf.5.shtml#plugin_aggregation "..the internal lookup structure won't work if you try to group by type."

Answer (score 0):

Try removing: `GroupBy "Type"` and it should work.

According to [collectd aggregation plugin documentation](https://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/collectd.conf.5.shtml#plugin_aggregation):

> There are a couple of limitations you should be aware of:
>
> The Type cannot be left unspecified, because it is not reasonable to
>   add apples to oranges. Also, **the internal lookup structure won't work
>   if you try to group by type.**
>
> There must be at least one unspecified, ungrouped field. Otherwise nothing will be aggregated.